# How to construct new object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I  construct a new instance of a defined object?

I have code similar to this but the `this.User = new User();` it doesn't work.

```
(function () {

SomeApp = {

    User: {
        FirstName: '',
        LastName: ''

    },

    Users: [],

    init: function () {
        this.User.FirstName = 'Joe';
        this.User.LastName = 'Blogs';

        //add user to list
        var copiedUser = {};
        $.extend(copiedUser, this.User);
        this.Users.push(copiedUser);

        //create new user
        this.User = new User();
        this.User.FirstName = 'Jane';

        //add user to list
        var copiedUser = {};
        $.extend(copiedUser, this.User);
        this.Users.push(copiedUser);
    }
}

SomeApp.init();

})();
```

Comment: I may kill somebody if I keep reading "JSON object"...

Comment: Look here - he had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: `JSON, or JavaScript Object Notation, is a text-based open standard designed for human-readable data interchange.` (c) [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). So, it is a string, **not an object**.

Comment: @VisioN, that's an oversimplification. It is a string that represents a serialized Javascript object, and can be put in a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: @Kiyura Many parts of an object and many values aren't representable in JSON and a JSON string definitively isn't an object. Your "one-to-one correspondence" doesn't mean a lot in this context.

Comment: I didn't contradict either of those? "One-to-one correspondence" wasn't totally accurate in both directions, I concede, because there is not a JSON string for every possible Javascript object; I meant rather that there is a unique Javascript object for every JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be able to create object using [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), you may create a "constructor" :

```
function User() {
    this.FirstName = '';
    this.LastName = '';
}
```

Side note : I'd recommend you to follow best practices in naming variables. Please read [this guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml).